# How to stop administrative password change

Tags: password, security, root

It is extremely easy in Ubuntu to change the administrator password by using the recovery console and dropping to root. Is there any way to stop a root user from changing the administrative password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Physical access == root access and root can, bu definition, do what s/he wants. This is why servers are kept in locked rooms.

Your options are :

1. Limit physical access - lock you computer .
2. Use Encryption (LUKS). Take care though, Encryption can be defeated if someone has physical access ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not only recovery mode can give access to root, also any live medial such as bootable USB or Live CD/DVD could also drop you to have sudo `permission`.

Some helpful notes:

- [Secure your Grub Menu with password](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-password-protect-grub-entries-linux/)
- Remove the ability to boot from USB / CD /DVD or any other removable media
- Secure your BIOS with a password

***BUT***  Any physical access to your PC means the attacker will gain root whatever  secure you think you are. Don't let anybody have physical access though you'll be in safe.